# Android и WiFi

Tags: android, wifi, webview

Добрый день!

Случилась такая интересная проблема, есть приложение для Anroid, в манифесте разрешен доступ к интернету.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Однако, иногда наблюдается такое явление, когда включена передача данных мобильной сети грузиться страница в WebView встроенному в апп. А когда включен WiFi данная страница почему то не грузиться....

Был отключен стандартный интернет в настройках и оставлен только WiFi, проблема не ушла....

Очень интересно что происходит, может кто встречался....

**Новая информация**
Выяснилась очень странная деталь. Если на устройстве включить Skype, то вышеописанный баг начинает проявляться. При выключенном скайпе бага нет.

Такая вещь теоретически может быть, ведь на Windows скайп жестко занимает 80 порт. Однако, как избежать этого в Android? Может быть как то указать порт для интернет соединений апа?

Спасибо!

Comment: Добавь ACCESS_WIFI_STATE в permissions!
Можно на код взглянуть?

Comment: `ACCESS_WIFI_STATE` нужен для того, что бы смотреть состояние wifi.  Но на нормальную работу интернет приложений не влияет.

А другие приложения при включенном вайфае работают правильно?

Comment: Да все работает корректно. У меня самый обычный webview с вызовом loadurl()

Comment: не может ли быть такого, что Ваш провайдер блочит доступ к этому конкретному ресурсу?
попробуйте зайти на ресурс через браузер

Comment: К сожалению нет. Ибо через пк такой проблемы нет

Comment: Попробуй открыть данную ссылку на стандартном браузере андроид!